# Insert element at the tail of a linked list, Python 3 hackerrank

Tags: python

[Python 3 Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list/problem)

I need to know how to solve the problem, here is my code (obviously incorrect) and I also attached the link of the hackerrank challenge. All of the previous answers is in older python and the exercise itself has considerably changed. All you have to do is insert data at the tail of the linked list.
Thank you very much and have a good day.

```
def insertNodeAtTail(head, data):
    if head == None:
        head.data = data
        return head
    else: 
        while head:
            head = head.next
        head.data = data
        return head
```

Comment: Please don't include any important parts of your question via links.  Everything important should go in your question itself.  You're borderline here because I was able to answer your question without viewing that link, but my answer might have been different/better if I'd had some of the information from that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

```
def insertNodeAtTail(head, data):
    if head is None:
            return SinglyLinkedListNode(data)
    pnt = head
    while pnt.next:
            pnt = pnt.next
    pnt.next = SinglyLinkedListNode(data)
    return head
```

Comment: If you saw my criticism earlier...I apologize.  I was wrong.  Your code is right as is me thinks.  I realized that you always want to return `head`, like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, right off the bat, I can see a big problem.  You check for `head == None`, and if that is `True`, then you proceed to try to set the `data` attribute in an object that doesn't exist...in `None`.  Also, you should be using `if head is None`.  If that succeeds, what you probably want to do is create a new Node object, set its `data` attribute to the incoming data, and set `head` to point to that new node.

You have a similar issue with the other half of your code.  Your code doesn't add a Node in the case of an existing list either...it just changes the data that the last Node in the list is pointing to.  Here, you want to create a Node containing your passed in data, and point `node.next` to it.

I don't know the details of how you create a node, but here's about what your code should look like:

```
def insertNodeAtTail(head, data):
    if head is None:
        head = Node(data)
        return head
    else:
        node = head
        while node.next:
            node = node.next
        node.next = Node(data)
        return head
```

It is assumed that `Node()` sets its `next` attribute to `None` and sets its `data` attribute to the passed in data.

Comment: @VíctorSamsonov if you copied this code, please do so again.  I was a bit mixed up.  Sorry about that.  The second part of the code wasn't right.  I'm pretty sure it is now.